# Aplanar lista y convertir string a set

Tags: python, lista

Tengo la siguiente lista:

```
result = [{"{'rueda-pinchada', 'rueda-repuesto'}", " {'eje', 'maletero', 'suelo'}"}]
```

y quiero conseguir lo siguiente:

```
result = [{'rueda-repuesto', 'rueda-pinchada'}, {'maletero', 'eje', 'suelo'}]
```

Como se puede ver, la segunda lista contiene dos conjuntos, mientras que la primera contiene un conjunto con dos string que "imitan" a un conjunto. La idea es aplanar la lista para obtener los dos strings, y con la lista de strings, convertir estos a set. Quedando una lista de conjuntos.

He intentado aplanarla de la siguiente forma:

```
aux = [constante for x in result for constante in x]
```

y ha dado como resultado:

```
['{', "'", 'r', 'u', 'e', 'd', 'a', '-', 'p', 'i', 'n', 'c', 'h', 'a', 'd', 'a', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'r', 'u', 'e', 'd', 'a', '-', 'r', 'e', 'p', 'u', 'e', 's', 't', 'o', "'", '}', ' ', '{', "'", 'e', 'j', 'e', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'm', 'a', 'l', 'e', 't', 'e', 'r', 'o', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 's', 'u', 'e', 'l', 'o', "'", '}']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que desenredar un poco la expresión inicial:

```
result = [{"{'rueda-pinchada', 'rueda-repuesto'}", " {'eje', 'maletero', 'suelo'}"}]
```

`result` es una lista. Esta lista contiene un *set* con dos elementos de tipo *string*:

- {'rueda-pinchada', 'rueda-repuesto'}
- {'eje', 'maletero', 'suelo'}

El contenido de cada string es la representación en texto de un *set*.

La función `eval` puede tomar un código python, ejecutarlo y devolver el resultado producido. En este caso, el código es simplemente define un *set*.

Entonces, si ejecutamos:

```
eval("{'eje', 'maletero', 'suelo'}")
```

se verá que el argumento (como *string*) crea un conjunto. `eval` devolverá ese conjunto.

**Código**

Usando comprensión de listas, recorremos el *set* evaluando sus elementos e incorporándolos a la lista final

```
nuevo = [eval(item) for item in result[0]]
```

**Demo**

```
print(nuevo)
```

produce:

```
[{'rueda-repuesto', 'rueda-pinchada'}, {'maletero', 'eje', 'suelo'}]
```

Comment: Es justo lo que necesitaba, no tenía ni idea de la función eval. Muchas gracias

Comment: @Jesus_jbs  eval no es usada por el riesgo de ejecutar código malicioso, es mejor literal_eval de la biblioteca ast  ya que esta solo interpreta los objetos propios de python

Comment: @tincopasan gracias por el aviso, lo cambiaré.